# Notation in Munkres' Elements of Algebraic Topology

Tags: notation

What is $ R^{N}  $ in section 1 of chapter 1 of the book *Elements of Algebraic Topology* by *J.R. Munkres*? Is $ N $ some natural number?

Comment: To be honest, if you're not sure about this, you might want to try improving your fundamentals. Munkres' book states in the preface that `We assume the student has some background in both general topology and algebra.`

Comment: Yes, this is very basic. You should probably master Topology by Munkres before moving on to this book.

Comment: And exactly why do you think my fundamentals are lacking? Something made me think it was $ \mathbb{R}^{\omega} $ and I just wanted to make sure I had the right thing in mind. Please don't be judgmental.

Comment: @swaqar: I thought that because you gave no indication you knew any potential meaning of $\mathbb{R}^N$, and because you didn't use $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbf{R}$ for the real numbers. Please try to explain your own thoughts further, and use accepted notation, when asking questions.

Comment: People sometimes get confused due to notation. Perhaps $\mathbb{R}^n$ is much more common.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah $N$ is a natural number. It's just the standard $N$ dimensional real vector space.